# Is there a way to override 'nr_hugepages' via boot parameters in kernel 2.6 (CentOs 6.8)

Tags: linux, centos, boot, kernel

Set `vm.nr_hugepages` too high in `/etc/sysctl.conf` and the kernel panic during boot due to not having enough memory.
Is there a way to disable this via a boot parameter in grub menu?
Tried `hugepages=0`, `mem=16G`, `vm.nr_hugepages=0`.

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/sysctl.conf` is loaded by a service during boot. If you boot into single user mode with the `single` kernel parameter, you should be able to get to a point where you can fix it, before that service has run.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't mention, but earlier I tried single as well, but still had the same error.

Comment: @Jeevaka You are meant to fix the configuration while booted into single user mode. Are you saying that the sysctl was set even in single user mode?

Comment: Even in the single user mode kernel paniced and the first two lines of the error complained about memory not being available and no processes to kill. Which, I assume, was caused by above config change. My system admin tried this as well. Later he managed to boot in a different way (network boot?) and commented out above line and the machine rebooted fine after that.

Comment: A network boot would have worked. Another possible approach would have been booting with `init=/bin/bash`. That will skip anything outside initrd, so it will be necessary to remount the root filesystem to read/write mode manually with `mount -o remount,rw /` before doing anything else.